# Choosing work or home contact info to autofill Pages template

Tags: pages

Certain templates in Pages '09 autofill using my work contact information, e.g., San Francisco Letter. How can I change it so that my personal contact information is used to autofill that data? I'm interested in making a one-time change, not a permanent change.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can make change by opening the Inspector and selecting the "Link Inspector" tab there. There you are presented with a 3 additional preferences "Hyperlink", "Bookmark" and "Merge". In the "Merge" preference you can find each line of your address and select the appropriate one. This is provided that you have correctly set you Home and Work addresses in your Address Book.